# Java beginner with some doubts in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

**How to establish JDBC connectivity** and **how to find the localhost**
please solve my problem and explain my code error with explanation that i have to concentrate and **how to print the fields of database in j swing**

```
package swingtesting;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
     Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
       try{
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:3535;DatabaseName=swingmail;User=sa;Password=sa;");
       st=con.createStatement();
       String qry=" select * from empmail";
       rs=st.executeQuery(qry);
       System.out.println(rs.getString("empid"));
       System.out.println(rs.getString("empname"));
       System.out.println(rs.getString("desg"));
       System.out.println(rs.getString("basic"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}

    }
}

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at swingtesting.NewJSwing.main(NewJSwing.java:130)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at swingtesting.NewJSwing.initComponents(NewJSwing.java:39)
        at swingtesting.NewJSwing.<init>(NewJSwing.java:27)
        at swingtesting.NewJSwing$2.run(NewJSwing.java:122)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: wat is the issue here? You haven't shared the code error?

Comment: Nothing about this code uses Swing, so it might help to clean up your question to just the pertinent elements. Also any compile time or runtime errors would help.

Comment: I just want to know how to print the fields in database on j swing in frames

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking for the description of your code. First you need to read upon few things

- JDBC API
- JDBC Driver Manager
- JDBC-ODBC Bridge

Now, The description of your code goes like

- `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");` This loads the Driver class and returns its instance, This hides all the complexity of socket establishment and invoking native code etc.
- `DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);` This establishes a connection to the database with the given URL and credentials. Each driver specifies its own standards to define the URL, you find them on their documentation.
- `st=con.createStatement();` Once the connection is established you can execute multiple statements (queries) on a single connection. You need to call this statements for each query you want to fire against a database.
- `rs=st.executeQuery(qry);` Finally executing the query and accepting the results of your query, They will wraped into `ResultSet` which follows iterator pattern.

Once you get the result set, It will have all the rows of your query result. You need to iterate through it to get all the rows, example is as follows

```
while( rs.next() ) { 
   String empId = rs.getString("empid");
   System.out.println( empId);
   //other fields
}
```

You can find lot of information and help on google. Go through them once.

**UPDATE** (After OP edit)
The exception clearly saying that the driver class not found on classapth.
Add the sqlserver's jdbc jar to the classpath.

Comment: Pretty much sure now abt jdbc and i have got some idea and now can handle JDBC somewhat

Comment: Ok, The error you mentioned is because your classpath missing that sqljdbc.jar, Add that to your classpath.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1300669/rp thank u